# How to create a dynamic file with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to have a route send back a custom generated file using Meteor. An example would be having a route such as `https://example.com/image?text=hello+world` and having it send a image with the text "hello world" rendered.

How would I do this? Is there a way to have access to req and res variables like when using express as a webserver? I basically need a `res.send()` for meteor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question about server-side routing. There are multiple options for that. Still the most popular is probably [iron-router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/). Using that you could write:

```js
Router.route('/image', function () {
  const text = this.params.query.text;
  const image = callMagicFunctionToGenerateImageFrom(text);
  this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png'););
  this.response.write(image);
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Here `this.response` is a [node.js HTTP Response object](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).